# Algorithm to get recursive nested values

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm writing a program that first must match an item with `name` === `searchValue`, then i need his `programParent` item recursively. Example: first match is: `{ id: '25', name: 'ventas OUT Personal plus', programParent: '24' }` so his parent is: `{ id: '24', name: 'ventas OUT Personal', programParent: '23' }` & his parent is: `{ id: '23', name: 'ventas', programParent: '' }`. An empty string represents the last parent.

```js
const programs = [
    { id: '23', name: 'ventas', programParent: '' },
    { id: '24', name: 'ventas OUT Personal', programParent: '23' },
    { id: '25', name: 'ventas OUT Personal plus', programParent: '24' },
    { id: '26', name: 'ventas IN Hogares', programParent: '23' },
    { id: '27', name: 'Ad Hoc', programParent: '' },
    { id: '28', name: 'Ad Hoc asd', programParent: '27' },
    { id: '29', name: 'Ad Hoc 123', programParent: '27' },
    { id: '30', name: 'ventas IN Personal plus', programParent: '26' },
]

const searchValue = 'ventas OUT Personal plus'

const filteredPrograms = programs.filter(x => x.name === searchValue)
console.log(filteredPrograms)

const result = []

for (let i = 0; i < filteredPrograms.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < programs.length; j++) {
    if (filteredPrograms[i].programParent === programs[j].id) {
      result.push(programs[j])
    }

  }
}

console.log(result)

// const expected = [
//   { id: '25', name: 'ventas OUT Personal plus', programParent: '24' },
//   { id: '24', name: 'ventas OUT Personal', programParent: '23' },
//   { id: '23', name: 'ventas', programParent: '' }
// ]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take a single loop for searching and building a hash table for all `id` and their objects.

At the end get the last object of result and take the parent until no more parents are available.

```js
const
    programs = [{ id: '23', name: 'ventas', programParent: '' }, { id: '24', name: 'ventas OUT Personal', programParent: '23' }, { id: '25', name: 'ventas OUT Personal plus', programParent: '24' }, { id: '26', name: 'ventas IN Hogares', programParent: '23' }, { id: '27', name: 'Ad Hoc', programParent: '' }, { id: '28', name: 'Ad Hoc asd', programParent: '27' }, { id: '29', name: 'Ad Hoc 123', programParent: '27' }, { id: '30', name: 'ventas IN Personal plus', programParent: '26' }],
    searchValue = 'ventas OUT Personal plus',
    result = [],
    ids = {};

for (const program of programs) {
    if (program.name === searchValue) result.push(program);
    ids[program.id] = program;
}

while (result.at(-1).programParent)
    result.push(ids[result.at(-1).programParent]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const programs = [
    { id: '23', name: 'ventas', programParent: '' },
    { id: '24', name: 'ventas OUT Personal', programParent: '23' },
    { id: '25', name: 'ventas OUT Personal plus', programParent: '24' },
    { id: '26', name: 'ventas IN Hogares', programParent: '23' },
    { id: '27', name: 'Ad Hoc', programParent: '' },
    { id: '28', name: 'Ad Hoc asd', programParent: '27' },
    { id: '29', name: 'Ad Hoc 123', programParent: '27' },
    { id: '30', name: 'ventas IN Personal plus', programParent: '26' },
]

const graphLookup = (startWith) => {
  if(!startWith) return [];
  const ancestors = [startWith];
  let parent = startWith;
  while(parent) {
    parent = programs.find(p => p.id === parent.programParent);
    parent && ancestors.push(parent);
  }
  return ancestors;
}

const lookupAncestors = (searchValue) => {
  const p = programs.find(p => p.name === searchValue);
  return graphLookup(p);
}

const searchValue = 'ventas OUT Personal plus';
console.log(lookupAncestors(searchValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

This older question was recently resurrected with a new answer, so I thought I'd throw in another approach.

We use two functions. `hierarchy` takes a list of programs and one entry of it and recursively finds the list of its ancestors. And `pathTo` takes a list of programs and a name, for the first element list with that name.  If it's not there, it returns an empty list.  If it is, it returns a list containing that element followed by the result of a call to `hierarchy` using it.

The code ends up fairly simple:

```js
const hierarchy = (ps, {programParent}, p = ps.find(({id}) => id == programParent)) => 
  p ? [p, ...hierarchy(ps, p)] : []

const pathTo = (ps, name, p = ps.find(({name:n}) => name == n)) => 
  p ? [p, ...hierarchy(ps, p)]: []

const programs = [{id: '23', name: 'ventas', programParent: ''}, {id: '24', name: 'ventas OUT Personal', programParent: '23'}, {id: '25', name: 'ventas OUT Personal plus', programParent: '24'}, {id: '26', name: 'ventas IN Hogares', programParent: '23'}, {id: '27', name: 'Ad Hoc', programParent: ''}, {id: '28', name: 'Ad Hoc asd', programParent: '27'}, {id: '29', name: 'Ad Hoc 123', programParent: '27' }, {id: '30', name: 'ventas IN Personal plus', programParent: '26'}]

console.log(pathTo(programs, 'ventas OUT Personal plus'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

In the end, this is the same algorithm as expressed in the answer from Lin Du, but with a very different coding style.  Nina's answer has a significantly different approach.